# Getting IP address

Tags: asp.net, html

How to get and display the current viewer IP address in a text box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [HttpRequest.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property, or the REMOTE_ADDR key of the [HttpRequest.ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) collection, they are both `string`, and you only have to assign its value to your TextBox:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: This will, of course, only get the IP address that the request came from - which might (thanks to proxies, NAT, etc) not be any that actually belong to the visitor's computer (but there is no way to reliably gather that information).

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// IP Adress of computer
/// </summary>
/// <returns>return a string value(Ip address)</returns>
public static string IPaddress()
{
    String strHostName = "";
    strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
    string IPaddress = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
    {
        IPaddress = addr[i].ToString().Trim();
    }
    return IPaddress;
}
```